# 6 month expiration date on a javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm not great with javascript, but I have one that is working, but it seems like it's not following the 6 month expiration date that I set.  Can someone help troubleshoot?  This is what I have when setting the cookie's expiration date:

```
expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days. 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
expDate.toGMTString();  

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name){........
```

Any help troubleshooting would be perfect and very appreciated!

UPDATE - here is the script in its entirety.  I'm calling a pop-up window only to show if it's been 3 page visits, and 20%, and 6 months expiration date.  Just piecing it together so take it easy on me!!

```
expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days. 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
expDate.toGMTString();  

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name){

var dc = document.cookie;
var prefix = name + "=";
var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
if (begin == -1){
begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
if (begin != 0) return null;}
else{begin += 2;}
var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
if (end == -1){end = dc.length;}
return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}


    visits = getCookie('nVisits');
    if (!visits) {
        visits = 1
    };
    if (visits == 3) 
    if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20)
    {
      window.open("https://mypoup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    }
    if (visits < 3) {
        ++visits;
        cookieData = visits;
        setCookie('nVisits', cookieData, expDate)
    }
```

Comment: where are you *calling* the `setCookie` function? and what parameters are being passed?  also, if you used `expDate.toGMTString()`, then pass `expDate` in as the `expires` parameter, then why would you need to do `expires.toGMTString()`?

Comment: it seems that `toGMTString()` is obsolete and should not be used anymore, use `toUTCString()` instead. Maybe it's just that. By the way, what does your browser say about your cookie when you inspect it? (edit: and yes, it would be better to show us the call to setCookie in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Kaddath's comment solved the problem:

> it seems that `toGMTString()` is obsolete and should not be used anymore, use `toUTCString()` instead.

Comment: This looks OK if I have understood correctly, because it is a legitimate self-answer to the question which was copied from a comment that was posted under the original question.